# Copy data using vba in excel with specific condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My boss has asked me to fill out customer-rates in an excel file that contains 171 cities (each city has 5 different rates - ie. If city = Cell A1, the Cells A2:A6 = rates based on different weight classes)

I'm writing a VBA code (never done this before for work) that would copy the rates from the source worksheet to this worksheet after matching City-Name and pasting corresponding rates next to the city.

My code is able to scan and match the city names but it always pastes the 5 rate classes on the first row instead of beside the actual city it matched. I'm learning about the x1Down thing but it's complicated.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Button54_Click()

For Each c In Range("C2:C170")
 If c.Value = Range("O14").Value Then

*****O14 contains the source city name which I pasted from the source file. I can fix this later****

 Range("E2:J2").Value = Range("P14:U14").Value
```

****P14:U14 contain the source file rates that I pasted. I can fix this later as well****

```
 End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I would like help with the (xlUp) bit so that Range("E2:J2") would go up in increments as it scans the list for matching city name. I've been playing around with it but assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `(xlUp)` or `(xlDown)` you could use the row number of `c` to output to the appropriate matching row

```
Sub VendorStop()

For Each c In Range("C2:C170")
    If c.Value = Range("O14").Value Then
        Range("E" & c.Row & ":J" & c.Row) = Range("P14:U14")
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```